# How to save opened application settings in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

In Linux there is an option to save the currently opened windows such that when you shutdown and boot later, these applications are there the way you left them. It is similar to Hibernate in Windows.

Is there something similar in Mac OS X?

Comment: This question is not suited fot this site, please try superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Relaunch](http://wiredupandfiredup.co.uk/Relaunch/):

> Relaunch saves you time by taking Snapshots of which applications you are using, and starts them back up for you.

I'm afraid this is the best you can get.

Answer (score 0):

If you can stand to wait, Mac OS 10.7 (Lion) has this feature.